# Grails custom jquery configuration

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-2.3

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: No javascript provider is configured
```

I have this exception when using a taglib in grails. We are using jquery without the jquery plugin. How to configure our custom jquery files for grails, so that it recognizes jquery as javascript library?

Comment: why dont you use the plugin ? you can provide a version number if you want to have an explicit version

Comment: or simply use <script> tags instead of <g:javascript>

Answer (score 0):

In config.groovy you should be able to set:

```
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"
```

But if you are already using the jquery without the plugin you should probably just write the JS yourself instead of depending on a tag to generate it for you.